# Can some one tell me the major differences between Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, 11.10

Can someone tell me the major differences between Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 please?

Comment: see wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_Precise_Pangolin#Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_.28Precise_Pangolin.29

Comment: This question is subjective. What constitutes "major"? A better question is something like "Where can I find the changelog for Ubuntu 12.04" Something that will lead to an objective question.

Answer (score 2):

They are as TenPlus1 says worlds apart, here's a little more:

1. Precise 12.04 is LTS - means Long Term Support for 5 years with updates
2. Oncelot 11.10 is a stable release and is only supported for 18 months, so its life is almost up.
3. if you haven't upgraded you should firstly because you'll have problems when no support, also more programmes for Precise.
4. Precise has some wonderful new features and was considerable faster, smoother and clearer in every respect.
5. Unity as in the Dash and filters actually work much which changes your computer life

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between Ubuntu 11.10 and 12.04 is that a LOT of work has gone into improving Unity and a host of other features found within, that and the latest package versions, a lot of bug fixes and better driver support...